# UISegmentControl in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UIPageViewController` in it have I have 4 pages. One of my pages have `UISegmentControl` where the user either tap or swipe the page to change segments. I think it is inside UIPageController so swipe takes to different page rather than swipe action in UISegmentControl or might be some silly mistake on my part. here's what I have done. I have added two gesture recognizers swipe Left and swipe right. and done this in storyboard

[image: SwipeGesture]

Comment: Yes, because of the UIPageController, swipe is redirected to the underlying scrollView, which makes sense actually. Also UISegmentControl works on tap not on swipe, so I don't think you have a problem...

Comment: @deadbeef yes I got the last part right so I was adding UISwipeGesture so that I can redirect to segment control and reload tableView accordingly. Regarding First part so how should I go about it ? use a UIScrollView maybe ?

Comment: You have to make your gesture recognizers work together with the UIPageController gesture recognizer. It's done by implementing some specific methods in your delegate. I advise you to check the doc or ask a specific question about that. Start by searching "Make multiple gesture recognizers work together" or something similar.

Comment: @deadbeef I don't think it's about multiple gestures it's more of recognizing views in childVc while ignoring in parentVC

Answer (score 1):

Two solution:

1.Handle all swipe gestures in UIPageViewController.If you don't want to change your detail view controller,you can add a public func to change some values.In `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` you can return any view controller you want to present.

2.Use UIGestureRecognizerDelegate.If you don't want get this gesture,just return NO/false.(set delegate for gesture in UIPageViewController)

```
// get gesture recognizer and set delegate    
self.pageViewController!.gestureRecognizers
// decide if page controller should receive gesture
public func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool
```

Comment: Thanks :) I don't understand them completely but will give it a shot

Comment: Hi, I don't understand which delegate method should I use ?

Comment: I'm having  BaseViewController that is parent of all child VC when I add this code in if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[MYClass class]]) It's giving me  an error :(